# live sass compiler не получается настроить

Tags: css, sass

я новичок и учу sass по видеоуроку. дело в том что у меня не получается подключить live sass compiler так что бы он обновлял данные которые я пишу в файле main.scss.

я скачал архив с уроком что бы продолжить обучение, но когда нажимаю ctrl+s сам компилер пишет что данные обновились но на странице сайта не чего не происходит.

Вот скриншот самого архива и скрин что пишет live sass compiler

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите так как не могу пройти дальше урок ! спасибо большое

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: а вы страницу обновляете?

Comment: Да конечно у меня установлен Live Server, он после сочетаний клавиш CTRL+S сам рефрешится